# Graph Explorer: How to use with an Application account?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My network admin gave me an "application account" so I can write a Java program that uses MS Graph.  I would like to use the Graph Explorer with this account to tests this account.

The admin registered an application and gave me:
clientId, tenantId, clientSecret
And these rights:

- application:Calendars.ReadWrite
- delegated:UserRead

... and from the Azure web pages he also gave me this.
[image]

Can I use this account with the Graph Explorer?  And how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph explorer uses Delegated permissions, not application permissions.

You should be able to use the Postman Collection, however.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections

Comment: OK... but if I understand delegated authority correctly you have to authenticate as a user and also authenticate using the application account.  And the actual rights are "the intersection [of both sets of rights]".  How do you "doubly authenticate" with the Graph Explorer?